# Search Entries for Keyword in Control Panel not working

Tags: control-panel, search

Using version 2.7.3, when I try to use the Keywords field in the Edit/Search Entries box, I just get a spinning activity indicator, but never any search results.

I am able to use the drop down filters, such as Channel, Category, and Status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in EE 2.7.3 when Secure Forms is disabled. It is currently marked as "fixed in upcoming release". ([Bug tracker link.](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19977))